# Matlab Numerical integral improvement

Tags: matlab, integral, numerical-integration

I'm trying to solve the integral in the code below:

```
clc
clear all
%Enviroment Properties
f=15e9;
c=2.99792458e8;   
lambda=c/f;
mu0=4*pi*1e-7;
eps0=1.0/c^2/mu0;   
eta0=sqrt(mu0/eps0);
epsr=5;
omega=2*pi*f;
k0=omega*sqrt(mu0*eps0);
k2=omega*sqrt(mu0*eps0*epsr);
%square patch array properties
l=1.8e-3;
alpha_Ett=1.02*(l^3);
p=2e-3;
N=1/(p^2);
r=0.6956*p;
chieexx=(N*alpha_Ett)/(1-(N*alpha_Ett/(4*r))); 
%source and observation points
z0=3e-3;
z=2e-3;
y=0;
for x=5e-6:1e-5:5e-3
pho=sqrt(x.^2+y.^2);
f1 = (@(kp) (kp.^3./(sqrt(k0^2-kp.^2))).* besselj(0,kp.*pho).* (((2*1i*(sqrt(k0^2-kp.^2)).*(k2^2))+ ((sqrt(k2^2-kp.^2)).*(((sqrt(k0^2-kp.^2))*(k2^2).*chieexx)+ ((k0^2)*(-2i+(sqrt(k0^2-kp.^2)).*chieexx)))))./((2*1i*(sqrt(k0^2-kp.^2)).*(k2^2))+ ((sqrt(k2^2-kp.^2)).*(((sqrt(k0^2-kp.^2)).*(k2^2).*chieexx)+ ((k0^2).*(2i+(sqrt(k0^2-kp.^2)).*chieexx)))))) .* exp(1i.*(sqrt(k0^2-kp.^2)).*(z+z0)) );
f2= (@(kp) (kp.^3./(sqrt(k0^2-kp.^2))).* besselj(0,kp.*pho).*  exp(1i.*(sqrt(k0^2-kp.^2)).*(-z+z0)) );
I1= quadgk(f1,0,inf,'RelTol',1e-8);
I2= quadgk(f2,0,inf,'RelTol',1e-8);
E= (eta0/(4*pi*k0)).*(abs(I1+I2));
semilogy(x,abs(E),'Or')
hold on
end
set(gca,'FontSize',14,'LineWidth',3)
xlabel('x [m]');ylabel('|Ez| [V/m]')
```

But i get the following warning :

Warning: Reached the limit on the maximum number of intervals in use. Approximate bound on error is  1.2e+03. The integral may not exist, or it may be difficult to approximate numerically. Increase   MaxIntervalCount to 1132 to enable QUADGK to continue for another iteration.

Could you please help me to improve my code?
Thanks in advance

Comment: When posting code, it's important to make it as short and trivial as possible (while still reproducing the error of course). That's usually a bit of work, but you can do it! Try to boil down your example to 3 lines of code.